# Fastlane when updated FL_NOTARIZE_USE_NOTARYTOOL to true, failing with error as password missing

Tags: macos, fastlane, notarize

I have a working Faslane setup. Till date, I was using `FL_NOTARIZE_USE_NOTARYTOOL = false`, so far so good.

I try to move from `altool` to `notarytool` by updating the `FL_NOTARIZE_USE_NOTARYTOOL = true`, but I get the below error:

```
Shell command exited with exit status 64 instead of 0.
Error polling for notarization info: Error: Missing value for '--password <password>'
Help:  --password <password>  App-specific password for your Apple ID. You will be given a secure prompt on the command line if Apple ID and Team ID are provided and '--password' option is not specified.
Usage: notarytool submit [<options>] <file-path>
  See 'notarytool submit --help' for more information.
```

Here is my fastlane script.

```
lane :execute_dmg_notarization do |options|
  ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] = "anoopvaidya@xxxx.xyz"
  ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = "the-orignial-password-here"
  ENV["FL_NOTARIZE_USE_NOTARYTOOL"] = "true"

  notarize(
      package: options[:path],
      bundle_id: options[:bundle_id]
  )
end
```

Any help and guidance will be highly appreciated.